# System.data.sqlite

Tags: windows, sqlite, mono

i need some explanation so i hope somebody knows ...

I downloaded SQLITE source from http://system.data.sqlite.org compiled it with build flags not to use interop, so i can use it with mono on linux.

On Linux + Mono the built assembly works without a problem... But on windows it says that it needs SQLITE3.dll.
Now my question is why? Should it be created completley managed without the need of sqlite3.dll ? or am i mising something?

And we will not be building for windows with mono :D so Mono.data.sqlite is out of the question.

Best regards,
Lonko

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely managed, on Windows, you need to supply sqlite3.dll with the binary.
See here:
[System.data.sqlite homepage: FAQ, question 11](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki#q11)